# nvidia-settings not working after reboot

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

It seems nvidia-settings are getting wiped away (or are never really saving anywhere) upon reboot. There are several other questions like this but none of the solutions have worked for me.

I have tried:

sudo nvidia-settings. save apply settings and save xorg config. I created a git repo inside /etc/X11.

Every time I open nvidia-settings after reboot, "jean" monitor is set to primary. If i swap it back to benq and save it, the monitor is just changed between benq and jean. IE, if jean was there, it makes it benq, if benq was there, it meakes it jean. See http://pastebin.com/cgdaL3iT.

Without opening nvidia-settings, i've commited both changes, and checked out both before rebooting, verified no changes were made after rebooting to /etc/X11, and still, jeanq is always the primary monitor upon startup.

~/.config/monitors.xml was changed to make benq the primary monitor. This hasn't changed either upon reboots. Doesn't make a difference. config is found here http://pastebin.com/ivjYQc7u

Another solution was to comment out the first few lines in here /etc/init/gpu-manager.conf which I also tried, doesn't make a difference.

ubuntu 15.04
ii  nvidia-settings                                      346.59-0ubuntu1
driver: nvidia binary driver version 346.59 from nvidia-346 (proprietary,tested)

hackey solution:

An interesting point to note, if i run this from .profile, it gets overridden. I had to add it into a script, do a sleep before it, and background it in ~/.profile as whatever executes after ~/.profile is overwriting this
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --primary

Comment: What do you mean by `/etc/X11`? Do you mean `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`? The files under `etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`? There's no reason for any changes to be made in `/etc/X11` itself. Can you confirm that an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file is created when you save to xorg.conf? If one is created, can you post it (include it in your question, you can use the `{}` button to format it as code)?

Comment: It seems like the same problem I had as well yesterday: http://askubuntu.com/questions/635349/cant-switch-to-dedicated-nvidia-graphics-card

Comment: the git repo was made in the directory /etc/X11. The file that was changed was xorg.conf.  see the pastebin i posted for a diff http://pastebin.com/cgdaL3iT. The full xorg.conf is here http://pastebin.com/LizRhR4R

Comment: @terdon why do you claim that nothing should be changed inside /etc/X11?  Many questions in this stackexchange refer to using `sudo nvidia-xconfig` which does just that.  e.g., http://askubuntu.com/a/281550/340383 and of which fail for me too. In my case I want to simply reorder the horizontal display of a dual monitor setup, but nothing I've tried stays persistent between reboots.

Comment: @bgoodr please read my comment again.

Comment: @terdon I stand corrected. You were referring to `/etc/X11` whereas `sudo nvidia-xconfig` changes `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.