# Remove panning viewport

Tags: nvidia, xorg, desktop-environments

To correct for TV overscan, I have entered a value of 50 for understanding NVIDIA X Server Settings. This works fine for the current session, however upon restart the Windows still looks like it fits (side and top bars visible) however upon moving the mouse all the way to the right side of bottom, the screen will pan over to previously unseen desktop.

This would be moderately acceptable, except this panning seems to break the mouse location functionality, where as the mouse gets closer to the bottom right, clicks get overcorrected with regard to the larger desktop, and are registered to the upper left of the mouse.

Manually going back into NVIDIA X Server settings and changing the Underscan value slightly and applying again solves the problem.

Is there anyway to fix this such that I don't have to manually go in to NVIDIA anymore? I have tried the "Save to X Configuration File" button, to no avail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to understand nvidia-settings save configuration options?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/280972/how-to-understand-nvidia-settings-save-configuration-options)

Answer (score 0):

Run the nvidia settings by starting from a terminal and executing the following command:

```
sudo -i nvidia-xconfig
```

You should now have the proper permission to save the file.

[there is some more info here](https://askubuntu.com/a/281550/167115)